# Fill a field with a prefered string if it is empty

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
select  address from rmgr.avarii  WHERE vlan =? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

It returns empty string or string with address(accrording to **vlan**). I want to change this query, so when it should return an empty string, it must return "not available". Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Isn't an empty string very different from a NULL (when no records found)? So, you simply want to return a string when no address is present in the table for your input. Right?

Comment: Yeah, there is no record with particular vlan.

Answer (score 1):

This should replace NULL values as well as empty strings with a text of your choice.

```
select coalesce(NULLIF(column_name,''), 'No Address Available') from tab;
```

Comment: Edited my answer to address empty strings as well as NULLs

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` in the query:

```
select IF(address > ''),address,'not available') from ...
```

Comparing `address > ''` will handle both empty strings and NULLs.

Comment: Should it be        if + end if construction? Mysql returns the error after your query

Comment: Yes. The ... ellipsis is for you to complete your specific query. Here's a complete example to illustrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d44af7

Comment: hmm, I only see table creation and inserting. No select query. I made it like that, but it doesent work:select IF(address >"",address,'not available')  as address

Comment: Strange, well it's public, maybe someone messed with it. Anyway it was: "select id, if(type > '', type, 'not available') from supportContacts". Paste this on the right hand side and execute.